# Should I implement layout first or code?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

I am new to Rails, programming in general. I have the web design done in HTML/CSS. At what point should I start implementing it to my code? Should I have the stylesheets done for it already before I begin coding? Is there a quick/easy way to do it?

I'm just not sure when to start with adding in my web design.

Comment: How are you learning rails? Any rails book covers templates, css and stuff like that. You should get one.

Answer (score 1):

I usually write my tests first, without worrying about the presentation of the app yet.  Once my tests are in place I then start to implement code to make those tests pass.  I keep the UI itself as simple as possible, with the idea that I want it to WORK first.  My experience is that the UI tends to go through several iterations as you work with it, but most of the functionality stays the same.

To me getting the app to be as stable as possible is job #1.  Then I can attack the presentation knowing that the underlying code is able to be relied upon not to be a factor in the design.

Comment: So from the sounds of it I should implement the design last. Work the tests, do the code and then when finished add the design? If adding the design at the end wouldn't that take out having to go back and modify the parts several times?

Comment: Rails is very good about separating the view from the model and the controllers.  Getting the models and controllers stable means that you can test ideas about functionality before you have to be specific about the views.  I use http://foundation.zurb.com to prototype the presentation, but use it more as a wireframe than a final design.  I guarantee you whatever you have in mind right now will not be the final look and feel of your web site.  But I bet you have a good idea of what you want it to *do*.

Answer (score 0):

I go back and forth between the code and the layout.

I recommend getting *some* code working, then working on the layout.  But you don't have to get the layout perfect the first time, you can go back and continue working on the layout after you get more code working.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start outputing the necessary data to the view from the controller and, after that, I would apply the style to the page.

Answer (score 0):

When I started out,  I'd get a complete HTML/CSS site from a designer, then start to wire in the RoR that already PARTIALLY existed.

I did this three times.

Your fundamental question 'where/when' to start adding code, is really going to depend on you, your app, your HTML/CSS.  I don't think there is a real answer to this.

What I did was start at app/views/layouts/application.html.erb,  and got the new HTML/CSS working.  But that was because the HTML/CSS design I was handed was for a single home page and one example secondary page.  Regardless, I think in the case where HTML/CSS already exists,  the first RoR file you're going to want to focus on is:

```
app/view/layouts/application.html.erb
```

As you get that first layout working,  you'll be adding stuff to your pipeline manifests, i.e.:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```